# Grad des Anthropomorphen -> Antropomorphizität

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology

Ich suche ein prägnantes Wort, um den Grad der Menschenähnlichkeit von Systemen zu beschreiben (also Kommunikation, Handlung und Gestalt). Hierbei bin ich über anthropomorph bei *Antropomorphizität* gelandet, aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob das den Regeln der deutschen Sprache nach korrekt ist und ich das Wort einfach so bilden kann. Ist das Wort korrekt, wenn nein, welches Wort benutzt man besser?

Comment: Was stört dich an dem schönen Wort "Vermenschlichung" (bzw. "Grad der Vermenschlichung")?

Comment: "...izität" ist eigentlich die Endung weiblicher Substantive, die zu Adjektiven auf ...isch gehören und den Charakter einer Sache ausdrücken. Also scheint die Wortbildung nicht so richtig zu sein.

Comment: @tofro ich denke, die Endung "-ung" impliziert einen Prozess, deshalb habe ich mich für Menschenähnlichkeit entschieden.

Comment: @BenediktS.Vogler So wie "Zeitung" und "Umleitung" einen Prozess beschreiben? ;) Der "Grad der Vermenschlichung" wird oft für einen subjektiven Vorgang verwendet, bei denen Dingen oder Tieren Menschenähnlichkeit *zugesprochen werden* - Schlussendlich ist sowas ja rein subjektiv. *Menschenähnlichkeit* dagegen, versucht eine subjektivische Begrifflichkeit objektiv zu fassen - Das geht oft schief.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Bildung selbst ist korrekt, allerdings hat sich ein Rechtschreibfehler eingeschlichen. Richtig wäre *Ant**h**ropomorphizität*.

Alternativ ginge auch *Anthropoidität*.

Allerdings: Spricht etwas dagegen, *Menschenähnlichkeit* zu verwenden? Das wäre immerhin besser zu verstehen und nicht so holprig...

Comment: Wörter mit '-izität' wirken auf mich immer karikaturhaft intellektuell. Ich würde sie wenn irgend möglich vermeiden. Man kann damit Scherze treiben und von der 'Dickizität' eines Aktenordners sprechen oder über die  'Frechizität' eines Kollegen lästern oder sich über die 'Kompliziertizität' einer Ausdrucksweise lustig machen.